# Changing the maximum shared memory size on Linux

Tags: linux, memory

How do I change the size of the available shared memory on Linux?

```
root@thor:/home/omry# df -h | grep shm
none                  3.9G  3.9G  1.6M 100% /dev/shm
```

evidently 4GB is not enough for what I am doing (I need to load a lot of data into shared memory - my machine got 8GB of RAM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a function of the amount of installed RAM by default. It's typically 50% of your physical RAM. Changing sizes will probably require creating a new ramdisk or remounting the existing filesystem with different parameters.

See: http://centoshacker.com/kabir/tuning/tuning-tmpfs-filesystemdevshm-for-centos.html

Comment: I`m using ubuntu 11.04, and it does not appear to have the tmpfs line in fstab. so there is probably a different way to change that on ubuntu.

Comment: http://centoshacker.com looks dead/having problems - I get an http response but the content length is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Modify one of the `tmpfs`-specific mount options on `/dev/shm` in `/etc/fstab`. See the **Mount options for tmpfs** section of the `mount(8)` man page for details.

Comment: see my comment to ewwhite

Comment: Entering it into `/etc/fstab` should override the default mount for `/dev/shm`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
I have to accept the other question as an answer as it was the first one.